# PHP Function for factorials but using addition instead of multiplication?

Tags: php, math

I know that the mathematical function for `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1` is called factorial (and there is a PHP function for it: `gmp_fact(n)`).

But what is it called when you are wanting to add instead of multiply? Like this: `5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1`? And is there a PHP function for this? Or do I need to roll my own? I assume there is a function for something like this but since I don't know what the mathematical name is for this kind of expression I can't seem to find the name of the function for it...

Comment: I think there is no function for that, but you can make it your own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`n * (n + 1) / 2`

These are called [Triangular Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Comment: Oh yeah... duh. That is more simple than I was thinking... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add all the numbers into an array (or use `range`) and then use `array_sum`.

```
array_sum(range(1,5));
```